# DbContext Dependency Injection outside of MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a C# solution with two projects, ProductStore.Web and ProductStore.Data, both targeting .NET Core 2.0.

I have my HomeController and CustomerRepository as follows (I've set it up in the HomeController for speed, customer creation will be in the customer controller, but not yet scaffold-ed it out):

```
namespace ProductStore.Web.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly DatabaseContext _context;

        public HomeController(DatabaseContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ICustomerRepository<Customer> cr = new CustomerRepository(_context);
            Customer customer = new Customer
            {
                // customer details
            };
            //_context.Customers.Add(customer);
            int result = cr.Create(customer).Result;
            return View();
        }
    }
}

namespace ProductStore.Data
{
    public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository<Customer>
    {
        DatabaseContext _context;
        public CustomerRepository(DatabaseContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
    }
}
```

Dependency Injection resolves _context automatically inside the controller. I am then passing the context as a parameter for CustomerRepository which resides in ProductStore.Data.

My question is two fold:

1. Is this best practice (passing the context from controller to CustomerRepository)
2. If not best practice, can I access context via `IServiceCollection services` in a similar way to how the DatabaseContext is inserted into services in my application StartUp.cs class...

I feel like I shouldn't have to pass the context over, CustomerRepository should be responsible for acquiring the context.

FYI, relatively new to MVC and brand new to Entity Framework and Dependency Injection

Thanks

Comment: Why not inject `context` directly into `repository`?

Comment: @RubenVardanyan thats what I'm asking. I know I could just create a new context object from within repository, but if the context already exists within my applications services, I feel I should be re-using it?

Comment: see answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to pass `context` to `controller` to be able to use the `context` registered in services inside repository. The way I prefer to do that, is the following. Inject `context` into `repository` and then inject `repository` into controller. Using the Microsoft Dependency Injection Extension in for .Net Core it will look like this

```
// Service registrations in Startup class
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Also other service registrations
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddScoped<DatabaseContext, DatabaseContext>();
    services.AddScoped<ICustomerRepository<Customer>, CustomerRepository>();
}

// Controller
namespace ProductStore.Web.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ICustomerRepository _customerRepository;

        public HomeController(ICustomerRepository customerRepository)
        {
            _customerRepository = customerRepository;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer
            {
                // customer details
            };
            //_context.Customers.Add(customer);
            int result = _customerRepository.Create(customer).Result;
            return View();
        }
    }
}

//Repository
namespace ProductStore.Data
{
    public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository<Customer>
    {
        DatabaseContext _context;
        public CustomerRepository(DatabaseContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
    }
}
```

After this when `DependencyResolver` tries to resolve `ICustomerRepository` to inject into the `HomeController` he sees, that the registered implementation of `ICustomerRepository` (in our case `CustomerRepository`) has one constructor which needs `DatabaseContext` as a parameter and `DependencyResolver` trying to to get registered service for `DatabaseContext` and inject it into `CustomerRepository`

Comment: @Yaser, yes I missed the part of generics. But in this case only the interface is generic and not implementation. So, this approach should work.

Comment: @Yaser there was extra `>` symbol in snippest, that was the reason

Comment: Isn't scoped a better lifetime to use for dbcontexts?

Answer (score 3):

If you define your repository in your `ConfigureServices` method, you won't need to inject the `DbContext` into controller, just the repository:

```html
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        
  services.AddScoped(typeof(ICustomerRepository<>), typeof(CustomerRepository<>));
}
```

Then you can just simply inject the repository into controller:

```html
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  private readonly ICustomerRepository _customerRepository;

  public HomeController(ICustomerRepository customerRepository)
  {
      _customerRepository = customerRepository;
  }
  ...
}
```

The dependency injector takes care of injecting `DbContext` into your repository.

Answer (score 1):

*1. Is this best practice (passing the context from controller to CustomerRepository)*

> I think you're looking for something like a "Unit of Work" pattern.
>
> Microsoft has written a tutorial about creating one [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).
>
> I would also inject the repository in your controller instead of your
>   context.

*2. If not best practice, can I access context via IServiceCollection services in a similar way to how the DatabaseContext is inserted into services in my application StartUp.cs class...*

> If I understand you correctly, than yes, you can. Also add the
>   CustomerRepository to the services in your StartUp.cs so you can use
>   it in your controller.
>
> Mabye [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection) tutorial from Microsoft will also help you.