# Getting dependency injection to work for Entity Framework Core outside of a Razor .cs page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.1

This is for ASP.Net Core 2.1 using Razor with Entity Framework Core.

I think the question is how to define `ReadData` in `ConfigureServices` method?

Have tried to look at this question [DbContext Dependency Injection outside of MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554107/dbcontext-dependency-injection-outside-of-mvc-project), but still cannot get code to work.

Trying to set up database access with Entity Framework Core through another class other than the Razor page.

In the `Startup` class in the `ConfigureServices` method we have this (I think this sets up the dependency injection for the Constructor in the Razor pages .cs):

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))); 

//Add Dependency Injection references
services.AddScoped<IReadData, ReadData>();
```

This is a Razor .cs page and it works with the Constructor; however, we would want to separate the db look up into another class called `ReadData`.

```
public class MyPageModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly MyProject.Data.AppDbContext _context;
    private readonly ReadData readData = new ReadData();

    public MyPageModel(MyProject.Data.AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IList<Car> Cars { get;set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        var userName = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value; // will give the user's userName
        Prayer = await readData.FetchCars(userName);
    }
}
```

Here's the `ReadData` class:

```
public class ReadData : IReadData
{
    private readonly MyProject.Data.AppDbContext _context;

    public ReadData(MyProject.Data.AppDbContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IList<Car>> FetchCars(string carOwner)
    {
        var cars =  _context.Cars.Where(p => p.Owner == carOwner);
        return await Task.FromResult(cars.ToList());
    }
}
```

The dependency injection that works on the Razor .cs pages will not work here.
For example, in `MyPageModel` for this line:

```
private readonly ReadData readData = new ReadData();
```

it complains that a parameter is not assigned for the required parameter for `ReadData` class.

BUT, in `ReadData` if we add chaining constructor like this:

```
public ReadData() : this(new MyProject.Data.AppDbContext()) { }
```

we get an error:

> InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

How do we get dependency injection to work for Entity Framework Core in the `ReadData` class?

Answer (score 4):

Your `ReadData` class should take a context in it's constructor:

```
public ReadData(MyProject.Data.AppDbContext context)
{

}
```

And now you only need to inject this class into your model:

```
public class MyPageModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IReadData _readData ;

    public MyPageModel(IReadData readData)
    {
        _readData = readData;
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        var userName = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value; // will give the user's userName
       var Prayer = await _readData.FetchCars(userName);
    }
}
```

Let the DI container deal with creating your objects for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just inject `IReadData` on the constructor of  `MyPageModel`

```
public class MyPageModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly MyProject.Data.AppDbContext _context;
    private readonly IReadData _readData ;

    public MyPageModel(IReadData readData)
    {
        _readData = readData;
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        var userName = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value; // will give the user's userName
       var Prayer = await _readData.FetchCars(userName);
    }
}
```

Don't create instance of ReadData

<s>ReadData readData = new ReadData();</s>

let DI container resolve your dependencies as you registered `services.AddScoped<IReadData, ReadData>();`