# How does one use dependency injection outside of an MVC context?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, console-application, service-locator

## Core issue

Every example I see for dependency injection is paired with MVC for some reason as if nothing else exists outside of web projects. I take issue with this because there is a contradiction going on with MVC utilizing dependency injection but it delivers those dependencies through a [Dependency Resolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.dependencyresolver?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) which to me is just another name for a Service Locator.

#### DI in a simple console application

With all that being said, how do you use DI with a simple console application?

- When there isn't a convenient Dependency Resolver ready to use. How do I actually perform the injection part of DI?
- I see the disapproving tone around [Service Locators](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/), but what else can you do?
- You cannot pass the container because that's also bad practice, but again what else can be done?

#### Common confusion/frustration

I see a lot of programmers making these mistakes and honestly I can't blame them for it. There isn't a clear solution outside of MVC which is clearly using the *dreaded* Service Locator.

### DI introduces its own problems

Something I don't feel good about doing is pass a dependency through a chain of objects to use it in a deeply nested piece of code. This just feels wrong.

#### Example

This is a watered down example of something I am working on to demonstrate my concern. I don't like passing the SMTP client dependency through a class, just to give it to another class. You might be compelled to say "Inject the SmtpClient into ServiceClass then into EntryPoint". In my example I cannot inject ServiceClass because it actually comes from a Factory pattern.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var smtpClient = _container.GetDependency<ISmtpClient>();

    //When I do this manually I feel like it defeats the purpose of DI
    var ep = new EntryPoint(smtpClient);

    ep.RunAProcess();
}

public class EntryPoint
{
    private readonly ISmtpClient _smtpClient;

    public EntryPoint(ISmtpClient smtpClient)
    {
        //EntryPoint doesn't use this dependency
        _smtpClient = smtpClient;
    }

    public void RunAProcess()
    {
        /* More code here */

        //ServiceClass actually comes from a Factory, but I didn't 
        //want to make this example too long
        var svc = new ServiceClass(_smtpClient);

        svc.Send();
    }
}

public class ServiceClass
{
    private readonly ISmtpClient _smtpClient;

    public ServiceClass(ISmtpClient smtpClient)
    {
        //ServiceClass uses this dependency
        _smtpClient = smtpClient;
    }

    public void Send()
    {
        using (var mail = CreateMailMessage(message))
        {
            _smtpClient.Send(mail);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Almost related existing question

This is the closest SO question I found in relation to my query:
[DbContext Dependency Injection outside of MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554107/dbcontext-dependency-injection-outside-of-mvc-project)

Comment: MVC is not using service locator pattern. In service locator, you would inject something into your classes that is capable of resolving dependencies. That isn not normally done in MVC. Instead, an outside type (the container) resolves all the dependencies for your class, without the need for the class to be aware of what is resolving the dependency.

Comment: It is very simple to create a console app with DI. Just create your container, register your services, resolve an instance of an object and call a method on that object to initiate the actual logic.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Ok so I think maybe that's where I am lost. That statement right there "resolve an instance of an object" how do I do that? Is it supposed to be automatically resolved like the dependency resolver in MVC? That's the disconnect I am highlighting. The web server has additional plumbing that I don't understand.

Comment: @mason - "In service locator, you would inject something into your classes that is capable of resolving dependencies." I don't completely agree with this because I had the displeasure of cleaning up a project that was over utilizing Unity hard core. This project had a static reference to Unity's resolver mechanism and it was plastered all over the application. It was awful. Runtime errors galore due to poor configuration management. My point is, this thing just showed up all over the place and was never injected.

Comment: The container resolves instances for you. There isn't additional plumbing needed. You just need to design your classes properly. A good rule of thumb: don't use the `new` keyword to create a class that contains logic (only use it to create "dumb" model classes that just encapsulate data, not logic). I don't know what project you're referring to, so it's hard to say what they did wrong. Service locator is generally frowned upon, and it sounds like that's what they did. Of course you had a bad experience.

Comment: I highly suggest you watch [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B412). I didn't understand DI either until I watched it, years ago. It transformed my code, I started writing code that was easy to swap components out and easy to test, and that led to my first full time software development job and put me on the path I'm on now.

Comment: @mason thank you very much. I am going to study everything everyone is giving me very closely. I really want to understand all of this.

Comment: Nkosi & Keith Nicholas - I need to review everything you guys have given me and I promise I will pick an answer. I won't leave you hanging. Thank you guys (and mason) for everything you have given me. I will find the time to sit down and figure this out and give my feedback and an answer for sure.

Comment: @mason - I watched the video. I am not seeing anything I haven't already seen before. Only one thing has stuck out to me though - the instructor is accessing the container via a static instance all over the application. Is this acceptable practice? If the answer is yes then that is the epitome of my problem. I thought it was bad practice to access the container all over the place.

Comment: No, they are not accessing the container all over the place. It is the opposite of that. The container is resolving instances of objects - those objects have no idea what the container is, nor of any concrete types besides themselves. Other classes are only accessed indirectly, via interfaces.

Comment: I don't mean this to come off as argumentative, but literally the instructor is access the container via static context in every example he showed. The only time this isn't true is with MVC because of the resolver. In console application and WPF you just use the root of your app, in WebForms it's Global.asax, in MVC it is resolved. So my point is "Should I be accessing the container from a static context to resolve my dependencies?" I honestly cannot find another way to do this (except for how MVC does it).

Comment: Youre still missing it. All of the services that are being created have no idea about the container being used - nor should they. All they need to know is what dependencies they have, and they ask for those via constructor arguments. Nkosi's answer here is a great example of that. In a console app, if you're not using something like the HostBuilder that Keith's answer demonstrates, you'll still to manually ask your container to resolve an instance of some class and invoke an action on it (as Nkosi's answer shows, which is very similar to what was shown in the video) to initiate the actual work

Comment: Whether the container is static or not is irrelevant. It can work whether it is or isn't. In most apps you should only have one container, and thus static is just fine. The important part is that only the entry point should be accessing the container - all of your services that actually perform logic should not be aware of a container at all.

Comment: Are you understanding this now? You haven't accepted an answer yet, so I'm not sure if you still want more explanation from us.

Comment: I'm sorry I got really sick and I haven't had time to even come to my desk, been sleeping off a weird cold. I totally understand that the service classes are resolved by the container and it doesn't care about how it happens - everything is passed via constructor. Totally get that. What I am asking about is the rules of engagement when it comes to the container. How am I supposed to access the container in order to resolve dependencies? Based on your responses it sounds like using it via a static context is okay. True or false?

Comment: You only access the container from one place. Usually this happens in some sort of startup method, such as Application_Start in ASP.NET, Startup.cs in ASP.NET Core, or the Main method in a console app. That's the only place you generally access the container unless you’re doing service locator.

Comment: I was afraid you were going to say that. What I am still confused about is: how is it possible to resolve dependencies anywhere in your application if you can only ever access the container in one place? The video is using overly simple examples for demonstration, but if you think about a much larger application - unless you are accessing the container via static context you cannot resolve dependencies unless you have a situation like in MVC where dependencies are resolved for you upon controller access. The video does show access of the container via static context repeatedly.

Comment: The video only shows access of the static context from a single location. It's equivalent to the Main method in a console app if it isn't already. You *don't* need to access the container from anywhere in your app, just once in the initial startup. That initial startup will resolve a class that has its dependencies fully populated. And if those dependencies have dependencies of their own, those will be fully populated. And if those dependencies have dependencies of their own, those will be fully populated. Get the idea?

Comment: Avoid using the `new` keyword for anything except a dumb model class (a class that represents data, but contains no actual logic or dependencies).

Comment: Yeah I get the idea, this is nothing new - using the container was never the problem it's all about how to access it. I can't find a clear answer on how to access it. Therefore unfortunately the only answer I can come up with is "Access the container as needed. Just don't pass it via reference."

Comment: No, no one is saying access it as needed. We're saying just access it in one place, at the root of the app.

Comment: Then I have to say that's impossible to achieve. The mere fact that MVC resolves dependencies for you constantly is proof of that because you are not accessing it from the root of the app, you 100% rely on bootstrapping your container with the MVC resolver. In the case of WebForms you can use the ApplicationContext, in the case of everything else, you use singleton access from root. It's impossible in some cases to know what you need resolved ahead of time, that's why I was mentioning the use of a factory class.

Comment: No, it's not impossible. In MVC, you create the container, and tell MVC to use it to resolve dependencies. In Web Forms, you create the container, and tell the engine to resolve dependencies. In a console app, you create the container and then you have it resolve your first dependency. It's really quite simple - you're making it seem much more complicated than it is. Most of the time, you will know ahead of time what you need to resolve and factories aren't needed.

Comment: Ok - so here is what I am going to do. I am still working through something when time permits me to do it. I should be finished with most of it soon and then I will point out the full examples to you and the others. Factories are needed if you don't know what you need until you hit runtime especially if it is data driven which is my scenario.

Comment: @mason - Hi - as promised I finished working on my project: https://github.com/dyslexicanaboko/pro-mass-spammer - I want you to pay attention to the Transmission methods in the TransmissionService.cs what I have been trying to demonstrate is I have dependencies inside of these classes that I cannot inject without making a mess. If you are still up to it, I would like your feedback. Sorry it took so long, I only had nights and weekends to make this happen.

Comment: You could have a single TransmissionService, and it can have separate fields to store a ITransmissionByEmail, ITransmissionBySms, and ITransmissionByPushNotification. Those can all be dependency injected in the constructor. Eliminate PrepareForSend, just make it part of the Send action. And have Send select the appropriate TransmissionByX dependeing on the message type. That will allow you to test your class by injecting mock ITransMissionX instances, or injecting concrete implementations for actual running. Just make sure your TransmissionByX instances are thread safe.

Comment: So the only problem I see with this, which is why I am so resistant to doing it, is each Transmission method is dependent on data driven parameters. Also I can only instantiate one of the three types at any given time because each communication is only married to one transmission type. In the case of email MSFT long ago made it so that you couldn't use a single instance of the SMTP client to send email. Not sure if MailKit works that way I will check. You had to new up a client per email. This was to prevent abuse. I will check out your recommendation and see if I can make it work. Thanks!

Comment: You are way overthinking this.  Anything specific to a single transaction shouldn't go in a service's constructor. That way you can easily set these services up for DI. You can easily reuse an SmtpClient for multiple emails, not sure why you think you can't. And even if you couldn't, you'd just wrap the SmtpClient in your own service and instantiate a new SmtpClient on demand.

Comment: Sorry things blew up at work for me, fires galore. Finally had a moment to look at this being a 4 day weekend. I don't totally agree with you, but that's okay we don't have to agree. I will take a look at what I did again later when I have another lul in my day job. Regarding what I said about the SmtpClient for multiple emails - I explained it already but here you go: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.8  look at the purple block midway on the page, it is effectively stunted so you cannot blast emails - it will only serial send.

Answer (score 1):

Outside of MVC you can use `HostBuilder` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2

The general idea is that it works pretty much like the web version ( and will support console, windows services, and linux daemons etc )

```
 public static async Task Main(string[] args)
 {

    var host = new HostBuilder()        .
        .ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices)
        .UseConsoleLifetime()
        .Build();

    await host.RunAsync();
}

private static void ConfigureServices(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddTransient<IThing, Thingy>()
        .AddTransient<Stuff>()
        .AddHostedService<MyService>();
}
```

Your Hosted Service is like your main entry point and things from there will be injected....

```
internal class MyService : IHostedService
{

    public MyService(Stuff stuff)  // injected stuff
    {

    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's awesome, I am going to check that out. In all of my searching I have never once crossed this. Thank you for the lead.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a matter of misunderstanding the design principles.

> Something I don't feel good about passing a dependency through a chain of objects to use it in a deeply nested piece of code. This just feels wrong.

The core of your issue is about understanding how to apply a clean design which allows loose coupling and high cohesion. Whether it is Asp.Net MVC or console application is an implementation detail.

The watered down example in this case is not following a clean design as `EntryPoint` is tightly coupling to `ServiceClass` and also violates the [Explicit Dependencies Principle](https://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/).

`EntryPoint` in this example is not being genuine about its dependencies. If it does not use `ISmtpClient` directly then it should not explicitly depend on it just to pass it on.

And if `ServiceClass` is coming from a factory then the factory should be applied at the composition root and then explicitly injected into `EntryPoint`

Review the following refactoring to see what I am referring to

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    //ISmtpClient should be injected into ServiceClass
    //when resolved by the container or factoty
    IService service = _container.GetDependency<IService>();

    var ep = new EntryPoint(service);

    ep.RunAProcess();
}

public class EntryPoint {
    private readonly IService service;

    public EntryPoint(IService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void RunAProcess() {

        /* More code here */

        service.Send(message);
    }
}

public class ServiceClass : IService {
    private readonly ISmtpClient _smtpClient;

    public ServiceClass(ISmtpClient smtpClient) {
        //ServiceClass uses this dependency
        _smtpClient = smtpClient;
    }

    public void Send(Message message) {
        using (var mail = CreateMailMessage(message)) {
            _smtpClient.Send(mail);
        }
    }
}
```

So even if you apply [pure dependency injection](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) at the composition root, only the actual dependencies are injected into the target dependent.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I see what you are talking about and I get it, I actually mentioned that someone would want me to pass in what is produced by the Factory, but this is where the complication comes in. Not every object returned by the Factory will need ISmtpClient. I can't muddy the way the Factory base produces objects by injecting dependencies I may or may not use for one out of three implementations (three is arbitrary). So let's say I have ISmtpClient, ISmsProvider, IWhatever - do I really new these up and pass it to the Factory base just in case it is used?

Comment: @dyslexicanaboko I would suggest you show the code to better demonstrate what you are referring to. The so called factory actually sounds more like a service locator. My code addresses the code shown in your example.

Comment: I can't share it yet sorry. Eventually it is going up on GitHub then it will be shared. I tried representing the basic idea, but as usual it's not as good as the real thing. Thank you for asking though and when I am ready I can resurrect this comment if you don't mind to share it with you. I can assure you the Factory doesn't use a service locator, it's just a plain class.